# Creating new Conda env --- CondaVerificationError:The package for openssl is corrupted

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a new conda environment from anaconda prompt. The problem is, I get a CondaVerificationError and it points to a corrupt file.  When it comes to envs I'm hesitant to experiment. I did upgrade conda packages recently and I am thinking that's when the file got corrupted.  With these errors it will not allow me to create an env. If someone can help me here I would greatly appreicate it. Here's what its showing me...

```
(base) C:\Users\Nick>conda create --name myenv python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\envs\myenv

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.7


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2019.8.28-0
  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2019.9.11-py37_0
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_2
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-19.2.3-py37_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.4-h5263a28_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-41.4.0-py37_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.30.0-he774522_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.33.6-py37_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for openssl located at C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/ct_log_list.cnf.dist'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for openssl located at C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/include/openssl/obj_mac.h'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

SafetyError: The package for openssl located at C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/include/openssl/ssl.h'
has an incorrect size.
  reported size: 111253 bytes
  actual size: 35840 bytes

CondaVerificationError: The package for openssl located at C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/openssl.cnf.dist'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

Comment: It is worthwhile in this scenario to reinstall OpenSSL

Comment: should I go in and manually delete  `C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_2`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Anaconda handled the OpenSSL install, yes? In that case, I’m not quite sure the best way to proceed :/

Comment: I believe you have that right Will. It is a conda package

Comment: Seen the same. Try: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Answer (score 2):

The issue is recently registered here [I am getting an InvalidArchiveError in anaconda prompt when I am trying to install spacy. How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726576/i-am-getting-an-invalidarchiveerror-in-anaconda-prompt-when-i-am-trying-to-insta/62003521)

Not to duplicate the answers, the short answer is, delete all openssl* in pkgs, `conda install -c conda-forge libarchive`, for example, will reinstall openssl again fixing the corruption issue.

Answer (score 0):

I went to file explorer and manually deleted the package. That solved the issue. When I tried creating a new conda env, it'll automatically install openssl again.